# "read-only file system" error running Docker Toolbox in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, docker

Trying to start up Hello World application in Docker Toolbox.

OS: Windows 7 Professional SP1

Installed from [here](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox), no errors during install.

Ran 'Docker Quickstart Terminal', and typed

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

and I get

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
c04b14da8d14: Pulling fs layer
E:\Sanjay\Tensor\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: open /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/Ge
tImageBlob474134307: read-only file system.
See 'E:\Sanjay\Tensor\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

any ideas how to proceed?

---

Not sure if this helps:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.27-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.12.3 (TCL 7.2); HEAD : 7fc7575 - Thu Oct 27 17:2
3:17 UTC 2016
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.8 MiB
Name: default
ID: O5YY:NXSQ:PYYI:HHGU:6ZN3:3U7H:DICU:3QWV:ABUJ:EUFR:MAEU:MMNN
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 15
 Goroutines: 27
 System Time: 2016-11-24T18:11:38.478659087Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 3):

I loaded Docker on an old win8 machine, and things ran fine.
I came back later and got the same problem as you. Here is what I did. First you need to find the name of your docker machine:

```
$ docker-machine ls
```

Then with your machine name, run the command

`$ docker-machine restart <name>`

and that did the trick for me. I don't know why it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with some folders, and it turned out to be Windows permissions problems.  I could not fix these through Windows itself, but had to use CygWin terminal to run the good old `chmod` command.

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm not a windows security guru, and can't speak to the overall security ramifications of the following actions!  *Use at your own risk!*  Also, there is no 'clean' way to undo these actions.

Opening a CygWin terminal and running `ls -l` in my `c:\Users\<user>` directory, I saw the following;

```
$ ls -l 
total 1417
drwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM      0 Dec 11 06:23 Desktop
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators SYSTEM    174 Mar 18  2017 desktop.ini
drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM      0 May 15  2017 Documents
drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM      0 Aug 22  2013 Downloads
drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM      0 May 15  2017 Libraries
```

Note the files aren't owned by the user, and the access privileges are set only to the owner.  I first tried changing the owner to my username, using `chown` and that didn't seem to work. So next I tried this command to open up permissions on directories;

```
$ find . -type d -exec chmod 0770 {} \;
```

This resulted in these permissions on all of my directories;

```
$ ls -l
total 14059
drwxrwx---+ 1 rooster SYSTEM       0 Nov 18 16:36  Desktop
drwxrwx---+ 1 rooster SYSTEM       0 Dec 11 16:58  Documents
drwxrwx---+ 1 rooster None         0 Dec 12 11:05  Downloads
```

After this, I had no problems.

Given the `chown` alone seemed to have no effect, I recommend trying the `chmod` first, and then maybe `chown` if the `chmod` alone doesn't work.